# Export CSV button with tabulation as delimiter

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, papaparse

I'd like my react admin export button to export tab separated csv file, so i don't need to convert the comma separated file, by doing : Data=>Convert=>Select Comma.

This is the code i use (From React-admin docs) :

```js
import { List, downloadCSV } from 'react-admin';
import { unparse as convertToCSV } from 'papaparse/papaparse.min';

const MyExport = (records, fetchRelatedRecords) => {
    fetchRelatedRecords(records, 'id', 'trans').then(trans => {
        console.log(records);
        const csv = convertToCSV({
            data:records,
            delimiter:"\t",
            fields: ['Code', 'nom_exp', 'nom_dest','amount','frais'],
            columns:['Code','Nom exp','Nom dest','Montant','Frais']
        });
        downloadCSV(csv, 'liste_exp');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The options have to be included in the second argument.

This example works for me:

```js
export default (data) => {
    const fileName = 'export_' + moment().format('DDMMYYYYHHmmss');
    const converted = convertToCSV(data, {
        delimiter: '\t'
    });
    return downloadCSV(converted, fileName);
}
```

You can find more docs in papaparse:
https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config